# Is the Matlab Cascade Object Detector (using LBP) Invariant to In-Plane Rotation?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, feature-detection, matlab-cvst, lbph-algorithm

I have read that LBP can be used for rotation invariant feature detection, such as [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1017623). This makes intuitive sense to me, as LBP is effectively evaluating local image texture. However, I have read in other places that LBP *cannot* be used in this manner.

A Matlab tutorial [here](https://au.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html) mentions that the detector is sensitive to "out-of-plane rotation", but does not mention in-plane rotation.

My question: Is the Matlab implementation of the Cascade Object Detector (when using LBP) invariant to in-plane rotation ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sensitive to in-plane rotation too, because it divides the window into blocks and computes the LBP feature for each one, like HOG. Based on informal experiments with face detection, I would say that it should tolerate +/- 15 degrees of in-plane rotation.